# How to get querying stats on Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

How do I get stats regarding which db login user is querying most on my postgres database, which tables/functions/views are being queried most?

I also want to see what time of the day these queries are being run.

Comment: You mean monitoring? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring.html

Answer (score 1):

You should have enabled more details logging earlier to have it in logs. You can use pg_stat_statements extension for analysing long queries/functions... But both are first configured, then consumed